# vue js how to prevent click on element that already have click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I had a `sidebar` and `main-layout` when ever I clicked on thing outside the sidebar I want to close it. Currently I was able to do it through `@click.self` on main-layout but the problem is every element like div that don't even have a `@click` event on it also not responding which is very problematic since my content is live inside another div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use just @click on the main-layout this should work with any click on child elements, as the click will propagate to the parent anyway?

Comment: look at the question again I was asking the wrong question and it deserve to be downvoted xD I was going to ask how to close my sidebar only when i clicked outside the sidebar but if the element that I click for example searchbox (element that had it own clicked event) I don't want it to close the sidebar

Comment: For that you need to use `.stop` on the click event that you don't want to cause your side bar to close. (`@click.stop=`)